# Postfix: Possible to overwrite Return-Path via SMTP

Tags: postfix, smtp

I tried sending mails via SMTP and provied a Return-Path. Postfix seems to override my values with the "From"-Header.
When im sending Mails via PHP, I am able to set the Return-Path Header with the "-f" option.

Is there a way to do so via SMTP or is this impossible?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I know VERP, but I am searching for a solution without using it.

Comment: How exactly are you sending the mails via SMTP? The Return-Path should normally be whatever you sent with the `MAIL FROM:` command.

Comment: @JennyD I want a Return-Path that differs from the MAIL FROM

Comment: They are one and the same thing - Return-Path is how the final delivery encodes the MAIL FROM address. Are you by any chance confusing MAIL FROM with the `From:`header within the mail? Because those two are *not* the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Jenny, that did the trick! Indeed I was confusing these two things. If you answer the question I can give you the correct answer mark :)

Comment: Done - glad I was of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return-Path is the same thing as is used in the `MAIL FROM:` command in the SMTP dialogue. It is often, but not always, the same thing as the `From:`-header within the mail.

So when you use SMTP to send a mail, the address used in `MAIL FROM` must be the address to which you want any bounces sent. The `From:`-address would usually be the address you'd want a human to reply to.

There's also `Reply-To`, which may be a third address. This is commonly used e.g. for mailinglists - when the listserver sends out the messages, the MAIL FROM will be the email address for the listserver itself, so that it can handle any bounces. The From: will be the address of the author of the mail, and the Reply-To will be the lists's mailing address so that any response to the email will normally go to the whole list.